# Insert n rows based on condition value (n)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i need help with this issue in Python.

If I have some dataframe like this one:

```
  ID           Date       Constant
0  1           some_date   1
1  1           some_date   1
2  2           some_date   4
3  2           some_date   4
4  2           some_date   4
5  3           some_date   2
6  3           some_date   2
```

I want to insert the number of rows for each group based on the condition "Constant". So for the group ID number 1 I would like to have one extra row, for the number 2 i would like to have 4 new rows and for the number 3 two extra rows.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.Constant)]`.

Comment: Can you format your dataframe? It's hard to visualize what you are asking.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't that is right as it duplicates the dataframe by * n where he wants row level appends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a list comp to concat the dataframe + the number of repeats you need.

It's not very pretty, but I'm not sure how else to apply this to multiple groups in your dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.concat([
    pd.concat([data, 
               pd.concat([data.iloc[:1]] * data["Constant"].min())])
    for group, data in df.groupby(["ID", "Constant"])
])

 ID       Date  Constant
0   1  some_date         1
1   1  some_date         1
0   1  some_date         1 #repeat
2   2  some_date         4
3   2  some_date         4
4   2  some_date         4
2   2  some_date         4
2   2  some_date         4
2   2  some_date         4
2   2  some_date         4 # 4 repeated rows.
5   3  some_date         2
6   3  some_date         2
5   3  some_date         2
5   3  some_date         2 # 2 repeated rows.
```